# Flutter Futures: How can I make this StompClient connection awaitable with Futures?

Tags: flutter, future, flutter-futurebuilder

I am using StompClient to connect to my gameservers websocket endpoint. For the sake of using `FutureBuilder` of Flutter I'd like to have async/await features with this client.

Therefore I wrapped the StompClient in the following way:

```dart
class CombatClient {
  late StompClient _client;

  Future<bool> connect() async {
    _client = StompClient(
      config: StompConfig.SockJS(
        url: '${ServerGlobals.backendHost}/connect',
        onConnect: (frame) async {
          _client.subscribe(destination: "/gameserver/foo", callback: (data) => {print("foo: ${data.body}")});
        },
      ),
    );
    _client.activate();
    return await Future.doWhile(() => _client.connected);
  }
}
```

In my main logic I am using the whole like this:

```dart
final combatClient = CombatClient();
await combatClient.connect();
```

However this does not work because of the following error:

```
E/flutter (23147): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<bool>'
E/flutter (23147): #0      CombatClient.connect (package:app/combat/websocket/combat_client.dart:19:12)
E/flutter (23147): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (23147): #1      _DebugCombatPageState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:app/debug/debug_combat_page.dart:61:27)
E/flutter (23147): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (23147):
```

Regardless of the error I'd just love to know what the proper approach is. I always struggle when it comes to Futures etc. I can't find the right API usage to make my connection to the game server *awaitable*.

Comment: simply use [Completer<bool>](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Completer-class.html) class instead of `return await Future.doWhile(...` - the docs say: "A way to produce Future objects and to complete them later with a value or error"

Comment: Thanks a heap! Please craft an answer so I can give you credit

Comment: great it works, but you know I'm too lazy - feel free to write a self answer so that someone else could find it useful :-)

Answer (score 1):

Quoted from @pskink

> simply use Completer class instead of return await Future.doWhile(... - the docs say: "A way to produce Future objects and to complete them later with a value or error"

Comment: seems you are as lazy as me ;-) I thought you will paste some of your modified code ...

Comment: I am a coder - that's the same as being lazy :,)

Comment: yep, I know something about it :-)